# IBMs Integrated Virtualization Manager. CLI equivalent

Tags: command-line, ibm-hmc

For the next weeks I need to fill in for local sysdadmin and I need admin some VMs on IBM's VM architecture, VIOS I believe it called.
There is this web interface called Integrated Virtualization Manager to restart VMs.

My question is there a CLI interface in which I can achieve the same tasks. The Web interface is archaic and inconvenient... can't script it.
I would like to force reboot them VMs every night.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the VIOS command [`chsysstate`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011787); the shutdown-related commands are:

> To perform a partition shut down using the shutdown command on the client operating system:
>
> ```
> chsysstate -r lpar -o osshutdown { -n Name | --id PartitionID } [ -m ManagedSystem ]
> ```
>
> To perform a delayed partition shut down (white button shut down):
>
> ```
> chsysstate -r lpar -o shutdown { -n Name | --id PartitionID } [ -m ManagedSystem ]
> ```
>
> To perform an immediate partition shutdown (operator panel function 8):
>
> ```
> chsysstate -r lpar -o shutdown --immed { -n Name | --id PartitionID } [ -m ManagedSystem ]
> ```